# updating a varchar column with multiple select stmts

Tags: db2

I have to update a **VARCHAR** column of a table by concatenating values from SELECT queries from another table. I have build a query like

```
UPDATE url SET VALUE = (SELECT id FROM ids WHERE identifier='site')':'(SELECT id FROM cids WHERE identifier='cid')
WHERE name='SToken:CToken'
AND tokenvalue LIKE (SELECT id FROM ids WHERE identifier='site');
```

Here value is **VARCHAR**.

How should I do this?

Comment: You seem to have described your solution. try running the select part first alone to make sure it works as you intend, then do the update

Comment: I want to have put the value as '1:2'. The above query is not executing. But yes I am able to get results from select stmts.

Comment: You concatenate strings with the `CONCAT()` function or the operator `||`.